# How to configure oracle data base in Oracle RAC environments in wso2 api manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

How to configure oracle data base in Oracle RAC environments in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 ?
use oracle script or oracle-rac script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scripts related to oracle rac. Please follow the following guide.

1. Set up the database and users
2. Setting up the drivers
3. Execute db scripts to create tables on Oracle RAC database

Please follow the guide - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-oracle-rac/#changing-to-oracle-rac